# Need help. Redis works like a turtle with centos swap

Tags: redis, centos, swap, ram

Need help. Redis works like a turtle with centos 7 swap.

1. I create swap in centos 7:

   sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile count=4096 bs=1MiB;
   sudo chmod 600 /swapfile;
   sudo mkswap /swapfile;
   sudo swapon /swapfile;
   sudo echo "/swapfile swap swap sw 0 0" >> /etc/fstab;
2. Install Redis:

   yum -y install epel-release;
   yum -y install redis;
   systemctl enable redis;
3. When my redis db became more than 380 MB (380 mb is a ram limit on my VPS) redis began to work like a turtle. Because of swap.

Is any way to store all db values and keys in a base file, and use for example 64Mb of ram not swap. Without keys delete.

(P.S Sorry for my English I am from Ukraine)